# Site restore breaks old Newsfeed posts

Tags: newsfeed

In 2013 we're seeing a consistent issue when restoring, copying, or moving sites around. All of the Newsfeed posts come over after the operation, but they can't be further commented on, "Liked", or deleted. Here are the errors we're seeing:

> Microfeed - SPMicrofeedPostIdentifier.FromString Exception caught [Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException: ServerErrorPublishedFeedListNotFound
>
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException: The target of the operation was not found. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 5.

Is this a known behavior as a portability issue with the Newsfeeds, or are we missing a step in the process? Future posts behave as expected.

Comment: you are restoring in the same farm or different?

Comment: I've had the same exact issue for both scenarios.

Comment: same issues in my environment.
We had also done restore.it didnt worked

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I am having the same problem and I have no clue how to resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no progress has been made. I'll start a thread over at TechNet and see if someone from Microsoft weighs in.

Comment: According to MS, this is expected behavior and only some custom code would give the ability to restore Newsfeed data for a My Site. I'm awaiting clarification on whether that applies to all types of sites. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/74582b78-2b36-46e1-aac5-86e3f9ee54c9/site-restore-breaks-old-newsfeed-posts?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with microfeed, I could't comment nor like nor delete it. The problem is the microfeed webpart is restored from previous sites, well at least in my case. The only thing I wanted is to detele them all, but they would appear again. So the solution I found was:

1. Go to your Site content with system account if it is possible.
2. Edit site content, all the post are saved in a list (Microfeed)
3. Select the "bugged" items and delete it.

Now all the post you create in the microfeed will be likeable, commentable o eraseable. I hope this could help your problem.

Cheers!